# Data query doesn't work as RecordSource for VB6's ADO Data Control

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2007

I used Access 2007 to convert an MDB database from Access 1997 to ACCDB format.  For RecordSource, both use the following query:

[image]

This query works as the DataSource for combining two tables into one grid when using the old MDB database, but when I use it with the ACCDB file it only shows the fields from the smaller database, not the combined ones.

In Design mode in VB6, the Data View uses the same query and shows the combined files. When I click Run in Access, it also works there.

I made a simple test program - a form with a grid and a data control. If I use as a record source "select * from Bids" it displays all the Bids table in the grid, but the query doesn't work to add the second table.

Unfortunately, I created this query about a dozen years ago and don't remember how I came up with the query in SQL format and can't make sense of the screenshot above; I've Googled but can't find how to get the SQL command from what's displayed in the screenshot.

I've struggled with the conversion for over a week, one problem after another, and each research by scouring the Web, but I am now at an impasse.

Comment: Go to Queries. Then right click on your query and select DESIGN VIEW. Once it opens, in the top right corner you should see a button that says VIEW, click on that and select SQL VIEW. That's how you get to see the SQL behind the query.

Comment: You are a prince among men!  I've clicked on View before and it just changes between the Table view and the view in the link in my post above. So I looked at View more closely and notice the tiny down arrowhead below it, clicked that, and there was SQL VIEW.

Comment: Added a new Adodc Data Control, pasted the SQL into RecordSource and got "Error in FROM". Pasted it into the original Adodc Data control's RecordSource, no error. Long story, short: deleted the new control, duped the original control with the SQL in it to create a new control - no error. It's been one strange happening after another.